# How to import simple JS scripts "globally", using ES6 import or require?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I need to assimilate some code into a React app. Problem is, that the code i want to use comes from some example i found on the web, which uses "normal"  tags to import various other scripts, via an HTML file.

The main script file that i want to use **calls countless various functions from external scripts.(The script "assumes" those functions are available)**. This of course works in the browser, but not in a build system like Babel/Webpack.

To make things short: **what would be the node/es6 equivalent of:**

```
 <script src="/dev/getHTMLMediaElement.js"></script>
```

And how do i make those functions available anywhere in the React app?

My React app is a fairly standard one, booted with react-create-app.

Comment: Add a line like `/* global someFunction, anotherFunction */` to your React script, and webpack will assume that `someFunction` and `anotherFunction` exist in the global scope. Now just call them in your components' methods like you would in a browser environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can require or import this file directly after adding `externals` option in webpack config

Ref: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/